# BDE Administrator closes unexpectedly when open database

Tags: windows-xp, administrator, database, sql-server

I don't know what happened on my Windows XP Home system for doing this, always worked perfectly but now when i try open a database the DBE Administrator closes unexpectedly without showing any error.
Here's a video showing what is happening: http://sdrv.ms/1bq9L16

Tried fixes, none worked!
Reinstall DBE Administrator
[The configuration of the AdminConnection\TCP protocol in the SQL instance SQLEXPRESS is not valid](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a11f5068-9c37-46e2-bc04-f1862969d938/the-configuration-of-the-adminconnectiontcp-protocol-in-the-sql-instance-sqlexpress-is-not-valid?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade)

Comment: You're using the Borland Database Engine (BDE) Administrator to manage a SQL Server Express instance?

Comment: @billinkc I get the same issue when I try open the DB with SQL Management Studio, I'm not sure if I answer your question.